# How to position this image next to the heading properly without affecting the design

Tags: html, css, psd

So I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, I'm coding from PSD but I'm having trouble positioning the image (the lightbulb).

I've tried positioning absolute and then adjusting the 'right' to position it next to the heading, but for some reason this has added some white space in between the section above and the section its on. Also, I want some padding above the image to make it neater but this just pushes the images downwards instead of adding padding above it.

Another issue with the way I've done it is when I change the screen size, the image moves out of place completely.

My CSS:

```
.lightbulb {
    position: absolute;
    right: 63%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<section class="what">
    <h2>What is a <span class="red-underline">style tune-up?</span></h2>
    <p>Just like a car needs a tune-up every 100,000 miles or so, your style may also need tune-up every 100,000 tears, smiles, frustrations, or laughs. Your life can sometimes takeover and your sense of style gets worn down, less efficient, and less stylish. A style tune-up allows you to give yourself a little refresher or a little boost VERY QUICKLY since all the work is done for you.</p>
    <p>It’s not just shopping, it’s not just color analysis, it a complete style experience customized to you, your lifestyle, and your style goals.</p>
</section>
<section class="how">
    <img class="lightbulb" src="/img/lightbulb.png" /><h2>Here's <span class="red-underline">how it works:</span></h2>
    <p>Send us your selfies – Take a picture of yourself every day for a week and upload your photos so I can get a sense of your current wardrobe and lifestyle.</p>
    <p>Phone consultation – Review your current style and photos. Answer questions about your current wardrobe, challenges you are having, a lifestyle assessment, and all your basic style stats like color, body shape, etc…</p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: search about: `vertical-align`

Comment: Please add your html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `:before` pseudo-element on the h tag like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qh9u9vba/1/

```
.how h2:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin-left:-60px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
}
```

And remove the `img` from your HTML. This will keep your h tag right in the middle and put the image wherever the text goes. Fix the margins to suit your image size. Good luck.

*Note: I added `text-align:center;` just for demonstrative purposes, otherwise the image would be out of the viewport.*

Comment: There's no image in your example just text

Comment: `background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50x50);` there's clearly an image in there.

Comment: Yep I had a missing semicolon, but it was working on my JSFiddle anyway :o thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Do you mind explaining a little how that snippet of code works as well? Here to learn as well! (:

Comment: Sure, consider upvoting the many correct answers you got in the post. Here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp is some documentation for pseudo-elements. They act as child elements of the element you put them on. `:before` puts an element behind another inline element and `:after`, well... after it. By giving the pseudo-element `position:absolute;` it is still attached to its parent (as long as you don't use `top`, `left`, `bottom`, or `right`), so using margins positions your pseudo-element wherever you want without affecting the layout.

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML:

```
<img class="lightbulb" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/50/50/3" />
<h2 class="lightbulb-title">Here's <span class="red-underline">how it works:</span></h2>
```

You can use this CSS:

```
.lightbulb, .lightbulb-title {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**DEMO**:

```css
.lightbulb, .lightbulb-title {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="what">
    <h2>What is a <span class="red-underline">style tune-up?</span></h2>
    <p>Just like a car needs a tune-up every 100,000 miles or so, your style may also need tune-up every 100,000 tears, smiles, frustrations, or laughs. Your life can sometimes takeover and your sense of style gets worn down, less efficient, and less stylish. A style tune-up allows you to give yourself a little refresher or a little boost VERY QUICKLY since all the work is done for you.</p>
    <p>It’s not just shopping, it’s not just color analysis, it a complete style experience customized to you, your lifestyle, and your style goals.</p>
</section>
<section class="how">
    <img class="lightbulb" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/50/50/3" />
    <h2 class="lightbulb-title">Here's <span class="red-underline">how it works:</span></h2>
    <p>Send us your selfies – Take a picture of yourself every day for a week and upload your photos so I can get a sense of your current wardrobe and lifestyle.</p>
    <p>Phone consultation – Review your current style and photos. Answer questions about your current wardrobe, challenges you are having, a lifestyle assessment, and all your basic style stats like color, body shape, etc…</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to vertically align the heading so it's exactly middle to the lightbulb? Apologies if I'm not seeing that correctly but if that's what you're trying to do, I've re-worked your code to make it easier to work with when using the following method. Here's a way of doing this using `display: table` on a wrapping parent element, and `display: table-cell` on it's children:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/4Tb/Mdb/4TbMdbeLc.png">
  </div>
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>
      Here's how it works
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
  display: table;
}
.row > .image, .row > .heading {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8mwL1h51/

EDIT: if you need the heading to be slightly lower than middle, then in addition to the above, also add the following:

```
.image img {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8mwL1h51/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

HTML

```
     <section class="what">
        <h2>What is a <span class="red-underline">style tune-up?</span></h2>
        <p>Just like a car needs a tune-up every 100,000 miles or so, your style may also need tune-up every 100,000 tears, smiles, frustrations, or laughs. Your life can sometimes takeover and your sense of style gets worn down, less efficient, and less stylish. A style tune-up allows you to give yourself a little refresher or a little boost VERY QUICKLY since all the work is done for you.</p>
        <p>It’s not just shopping, it’s not just color analysis, it a complete style experience customized to you, your lifestyle, and your style goals.</p>
     </section>
     <section class="how">
        <img class="lightbulb" src="http://www.greeklifethreads.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/blog.png" /><h2>Here's <span class="red-underline">how it works:</span></h2>
        <p>Send us your selfies – Take a picture of yourself every day for a week and upload your photos so I can get a sense of your current wardrobe and lifestyle.</p>
        <p>Phone consultation – Review your current style and photos. Answer questions about your current wardrobe, challenges you are having, a lifestyle assessment, and all your basic style stats like color, body shape, etc…</p>
      </section>
```

CSS

```
.lightbulb {

 }
 .how { float:left; }
 .how img { float:left; margin-right:10px; }
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want image and text align center than use below code

HTML

```
    <section class="what">
        <h2>What is a <span class="red-underline">style tune-up?</span></h2>
        <p>Just like a car needs a tune-up every 100,000 miles or so, your style may also need tune-up every 100,000 tears, smiles, frustrations, or laughs. Your life can sometimes takeover and your sense of style gets worn down, less efficient, and less stylish. A style tune-up allows you to give yourself a little refresher or a little boost VERY QUICKLY since all the work is done for you.</p>
        <p>It’s not just shopping, it’s not just color analysis, it a complete style experience customized to you, your lifestyle, and your style goals.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="how">
      <div class="test">
        <img class="lightbulb" src="http://www.greeklifethreads.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/blog.png" /><h2>Here's <span class="red-underline">how it works:</span></h2>
      </div>
      <p>Send us your selfies – Take a picture of yourself every day for a week and upload your photos so I can get a sense of your current wardrobe and lifestyle.</p>
      <p>Phone consultation – Review your current style and photos. Answer questions about your current wardrobe, challenges you are having, a lifestyle assessment, and all your basic style stats like color, body shape, etc…</p>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.lightbulb {}
.how { margin:0 auto; width: 100%; text-align:center; }
.test { margin:0 auto; width: 50%; vertical-align:middle;}
.how img { float:left; }
.how p { clear:both;}
.how h2 { padding-top : 10px;}
```